# Strange behavior of styles (Themes) in Android

Tags: android, themes, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

I got this styles for my Android app:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_new</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorAccentHint</item>

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyToolBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<!-- Custom searchView may be used or not-->
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- Gets rid of the search icon -->
    <item name="searchIcon">@null</item>
    <!-- Gets rid of the "underline" in the text -->
    <item name="queryBackground">@null</item>
    <!-- Gets rid of the search icon when the SearchView is expanded -->
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <!-- The hint text that appears when the user has not typed anything -->
    <!--<item name="closeIcon">@null</item> -->
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryTransparent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background1</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyApp.BorderlessButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.BorderlessButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyRadioButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Normally i have  transparent background on **Toolbar** of **NavigationDrawler** menu items click.

But sometimes theme in my app changes to **Holo theme** ,  and i can figure it out when its happens , so when i press menu items in **Toolbar** or in **NavigationDrawler** their background become blue, like in **Holo theme**

Where i have mistake and why its happens?

Answer (score 0):

Can you publish your Android Manifest ? Maybe some activities override the base application style ?

Comment: I bet AppTheme and Theme.Translucent aren't the same ? Your activities don't use the same styles...

Comment: Every android:theme attributes on activity node override the base app style

Comment: Theme.Translucent is standart style of Facebook login Activity. AppTheme is my custom theme. So what should i do?

Comment: You should apply your custom theme on the application node and remove any attributes on activities. I dont know if you have to remove the Facebook one...

Comment: Because your base theme actually is not your custom one and activities without style became holo